# Finding the mouse position from a mouse wheel event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

What is the proper way to find the position of the mouse in a JavaScript event handler, relative to the position of the element on which the listener was registered? I would have thought this was easy but is no matter what I can't seem to get it working across browsers. In Chrome I had `offsetX` and `offsetY` working, but these attributes are not present in Firefox.

I am listening for mouse wheel events using a jQuery plugin if it matters...

Comment: You'll have to listen to the `mouseMove` event and store the `offsetX` and `offsetY` from each mouse move into a global variable. Then just query those global variables in your mouse wheel event.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('someElement').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {   
        var mousePosition = { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY };        
    });
});
```

Hope it helps